# Fortran read binary file from C#

Tags: c#, io, fortran, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary in fortran. The file is created in c#.
In my example below it just stores to integer (4 byte I assume since the created file size is 8 byte):

```
string binfile = @"c:\..\bindata.dat";
int nrecs = 60*60*24*61;
int nvalues = 34;

using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(binfile, FileMode.Create)))
      {
        bw.Write(nrecs);
        bw.Write(nValues);        
      }
```

The fortran code to read the data :

```
program TestFortran

    implicit none

    ! Variables
    character(*),parameter      ::  fn = "bindata.dat"
    integer                     ::  numMeas,numVals
    integer                     ::  infile,ios
    character(len=11)           ::   acc, seq, frm
    character(len=128)          ::  nam
    logical                     ::  ex,op
    integer                     :: irec, nr,p
    ! Body of TestFortran
    print *, 'Hello World'
    infile = 10
    open(unit = infile,file = fn,status='OLD',access='STREAM',FORM='UNFORMATTED',action='READ',iostat=ios)
    inquire(infile,err=99,exist=ex,opened=op,name=nam,access=acc,&
      sequential= seq, form = frm, recl=irec, nextrec=nr,pos=p)
    read(infile,IOSTAT=ios)  numMeas
    read(infile,IOSTAT=ios)  numVals
99  close(infile)
    write(*,'(a,i8,a,i6)')  "Number of measurements = ", numMeas, ", and number of values in a measurement = ", numVals

end program TestFortran
```

The `open`and the `inquire`commands runs wihtout problem. In debug-mode it reports that after `open` `ios` is 0 and after `inquire` acc = 'STREAM', ex = .true., frm='UNFORMATTED', irec = -1, nam is the full path to the file, nr = 0, op = .true., p = 1 and seq = 'YES'.

when I run the first read statement ios = -1 indicating end-of-file and numMeas is not set to anything, same goes for read statement 2.

Does anyone knows what is wrong here? Every hint is much appreciated. I have tried to search for hints but haven't succeded in finding out what's going wrong...

Comment: The Fortran code looks correct to me. You could try to set integer explicitly to `integer(int32)` but most likely the default integer is that already.

Comment: I would try first writing a file and reading it back in in fortran.  Are you certain you have the path correct?

Answer (score 0):

so stupid of me... During debugging I had first tried without all the verifications, iostats, inquire etc.. I had also not included the `status='OLD'` in the open statement, whereby a 0 sized file had been created in the `../../` (base project folder) and not where I thought it should have been (in the `/TestFortran/Debug/` directory ).
Sorry guys for using your time in vain. But thanks for your quick responses.